# Can I carry 0.177 caliber airgun from Canada to India

Tags: airports, india, airport-security

I am an Indian resident seeking to ensure a seamless airport experience by proactively confirming details to preemptively address any potential issues.
Can I carry 0.177 caliber airgun with me from Canada to India in my checked in luggage as an Indian resident?